# Test accuracy different results per training despite fixed randon seed

Tags: classification, keras, tensorflow, cnn

I'm training a tensorflow model which classifies hyperspectral images.
The randon seed variable is set.
On one system I am getting the same test accuracy every time I train it (training is done on GPU), but on another system where training is done on CPU, I get different results with each execution. I'm trying to figure out what introduces the randomness.
Also, I tested on Kaggle again with GPU and there are different results each time.

The train / test split is identical for all of them.

Test accuracy:

- System 1: always 84.03%
- System 2: 87.5%, 89.67%, 85.26%
- Kaggle: 88.40%, 88.09%, 89.44%

1. What do you think introduces the randomness for system 2 and Kaggle?
2. How can there be such a big gap between all measurements? Is this a good indication that the system is underfitting?

Code extracts:

```
os.environ['TF_DETERMINISTIC_OPS'] = '1'

tf.random.set_random_seed(42)

input_layer = Input((11, 11, 200, 1))

conv_layer1 = Conv3D(filters = 8, kernel_size=(3, 3, 7), activation = 'relu')(input_layer)
conv_layer2 = Conv3D(filters = 16, kernel_size=(3, 3, 5), activation = 'relu')(conv_layer1)
conv_layer3 = Conv3D(filters = 32, kernel_size=(3, 3, 3), activation = 'relu')(conv_layer2)
conv_layer4 = Conv3D(filters = 64, kernel_size=(3, 3, 3), activation = 'relu')(conv_layer3)

flatten_layer = Flatten()(conv_layer4)

dense_layer1 = Dense(units = 256, activation = 'relu')(flatten_layer)
dense_layer1 = Dropout(0.4)(dense_layer1)
dense_layer2 = Dense(units = 128, activation = 'relu')(dense_layer1)
dense_layer2 = Dropout(0.4)(dense_layer2)
output_layer = Dense(units=16, activation = 'softmax')(dense_layer2)

# define the model with input layer and output layer
model = Model(inputs = input_layer, outputs = output_layer)
model.summary()

# compiling the model
adam = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate = 0.001, decay = 1e-06)
model.compile(loss = 'categorical_crossentropy', optimizer = adam, metrics = ['accuracy'])

# Train and fit
start = time.time()
resTrain = model.fit(x = X_train, y = y_train, batch_size = 256, epochs = 60, validation_data = (X_val, y_val))

classification, confusion, Test_loss, Test_accuracy, each_acc, kappa, classLabels, y_pred = am.results(X_test, y_test, model, classLabels)
```